# stripos returning false event if the string contains substring in php

Tags: php

I am trying below code:

```
   if(stripos($video["snippet"]["title"],$trakii)===FALSE){
                                    echo "here"; die;
                                }
```

Where value of `$video["snippet"]["title"] is Ed Sheeran - Eraser` and `$trakii is Eraser`

Why is it returning FALSE??

It is giving output as:

```
here
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think your variables has different values

Comment: try to use preg_match hope this helps.

Comment: var_dump those values rather than simply echoing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected for me:

```
<?php
$video = 'Ed Sheeran - Eraser';
$trakii = 'Eraser';
var_dump(stripos($video,$trakii));
```

The output is:

```
int(13)
```

You probably face some issue with unicode characters, a common pitfall.

Comment: yes issue was youtube was returning value with invalid characters...Thanks!!

Comment: Great to hear that you solved your issue. Though I wonder what an "invalid character" is supposed to be...